# How do I disable automount of USB drive?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, mount

I am running a RaspPi 4 headless and want to disable automount USB drive permanently. To disable automouont temporarily, I execute "systemctl stop udisks2". Thinkiing "ystemctl disable udisks2" will do the trick but it does not. After reboot and plug in a USB drive, the system will mount it at /media/pi.... . Is udisks2 responsible or automounting? What does it take so my Rasp Pi doesn't automount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in File Manager preferences to disable it.

This needs to be done in the GUI, either by attaching a monitor or using VNC.

If you don't use the GUI disable login to Desktop and enable login to command line.

Answer (score 0):

Check your run level with the **runlevel** command. Eventhough you are headless, it may very well be 5, which is normally for GUI.

If it is 5, then automount is enabled. You will have to switch to 3 to disable automount. The only difference between 3 and 5 is normally the GUI capability, which automount is part of.

If you are running raspbian, use the **raspbian-config** script and edit the system parameters to permanently boot into console mode (= level 3)